# After restoring a backup of my SQL db to Azure, all of my indexes are disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I was experiencing terrible performance after restoring a .BACPAC to Azure. I finally checked my indexes in `sys.indexes` and they all have `is_disabled = 1`. My coworker restored the same .BACPAC and did not have this issue. I have a couple questions:

1. What could have caused this?
2. Is it safe to simply enable them? Or might they be disabled for a reason (like being disabled while being rebuilt)?

The only schema changes I made to the db since restoring it were adding a column to an unrelated table and adding a new index to a table which previously did not have an index (this index is the only one still enabled). Thanks!

Comment: Azure support might be a better place to ask, though they do browse here.. THere's a developer support plan for a very low monthly cost, worth having

Comment: This has happened to me too. During DACPAC import, while it's creating the new DB and filling tables with data - there is clearly a step where it DISABLES all indexes, to speed up data load. Now... at the end of data import, it SHOULD RE-ENABLE indexes. Maybe that one re-enable part failed and that's why the indexes were left disabled.